# Protect Production environment in Gitlab CI-CD

Tags: deployment, gitlab, continuous-integration

We are trying to setup CI-CD using Gitlab. The documentation seems straightforward. But I am struggling with setting up proper access. We want to only give Gitlab admins to be able to deploy to production account. We also want senior members of each team to be able to create new projects as needed, provide access to others in turn and be a Maintainer of these projects, etc. But we don't want anyone outside the Gitlab Admin team to be able to trigger/approve jobs that deploy to productioin environment. I have been searching a while and still not able to a solid solution. Some of the solutions that did not work for us is configuring ci-cd jobs to be triggered by selected users. The reason is the project maintainers can updated the gitlab-ci.yaml file and change it if they wish to do so. Ideally something like protecting runners so that the jobs will fail if the person who triggered the job does not have access to the runners. This way, we can protect the production deployment securely.

Also, I have searched the concept of "environment". It only seems to be for labelling, and is not equivalent to physical environment that you can assign permission to.

So, what is the standard way differnet companies do this? i.e protect their production environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, it's not sufficient to rely on runners alone as an user/role-based access control mechanism because runners don't offer this level of control. Any user who can modify the project settings or CI YAML can cause any code to run on any runners that the project can access. You should require specific credentials/roles in order to deploy to the production environment. Your runners should be unprivileged by default and require jobs to authenticate and authorize to obtain secrets required for production access.

You can use [GitLab id tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/id_token_authentication.html#token-payload) to authenticate and authorize jobs to obtain such access. Among many other claims, GitLab ID tokens contain a claim of the user who started the pipeline/job.

As one example, you can [use Hashicorp Vault with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/). In your case, you may configure the vault policy limiting access to admin users, as identified in the `user_login` claim. Assuming your admin usernames are "alice", "bob", and "mallory", you might create a bound claim like found in the example docs:

```json
"bound_claims": {
  "user_login": ["alice", "bob", "mallory"]
}
```

That is to say, access to the secrets needed to deploy would be denied if the pipeline job was started by any user other than an admin.

The same principles can be applied to other secrets manager services other than Vault. Similarly, you can protect your [connection to cloud services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/) like Azure/AWS/GCP using OIDC claims as well.

Comment: I will give this one a try. thanks a lot!!